# Add json data to BigQuery table from Google App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I have some data in the datastore i want to move it to Bigquery , I know there is a method to move it to GCS and then to Bigquery using mapreduce but i want to upload the data in form of json directly to Bigquery using the bigquery API. Is there any big query API to do so?
Thanks

Comment: Like you say, there's a BigQuery API, so what exactly is the question?

Comment: i was asking which API , can you kindly provide the link or some example

Comment: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/developers_guide#gettingstarted

Answer (score 2):

You can load AppEngine backups directly into BigQuery. This feature is still experimental, so you need to sign up for the trusted tester program in order to be able to use it. More information is available here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#googleservicesdata